# Relative "crossing" percent calculation

Tags: javascript, math

I have this math problem. I need to know the formula to get something like this:

```
50% of (x) = 150% of 70
100% of (x) = 100% of 70
150% of (x) = 50% of 70
200% of (x) = 25% of 70
...
```

It seems easy but I'm stuck with this tiny issue. Please note, the `(x)` is a variable and is irrelevant for this calculation.

For more information, I'm calculating the offset for an image. The offset need to be relative to the resizing. Here's an example (the width test is 1920px, the original offset is 70px) :

```
50% of 1920 = 150% of 70 = 105
100% of 1920 = 100% of 70 = 70
150% of 1920 = 50% of 70 = 35
200% of 1920 = 25% of 70 = 17,5
...
```

The final code is in javascript.

*** EDIT ***

In fact, I just need to understand how i increase a value and at the same time decrease a another in synchronous way.

```
...
25% ==> 200%
50% ==> 150%
100% ==> 100%
150% ==> 50%
200% ==> 25%
...
```

There is the render (sorry it's made quickly)
[image: the is to render like that]

In fact, for my calculation, "70" is a constant. More my image is larger (>100%) more my offset needs to be smaller. This is also apply in inverted situation (my image is smaller <100%, more my offset needs to be bigger).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to know the formula to get this result (50% ==> 150%, 200% ==> 25%, etc).

Comment: So you need to calculate x given 50%, 150% and 70?

Comment: No, i need to get the relative value. In my calculation, i know that if my image is resized at 100% of the width, my "offset" needs to be 70 because it's 100% of 70. In that case, i know that, for example, 200% of the image width, the offset needs to be 17.5 because it's 25% of 70. I'm sorry if i'm not clear.

Comment: Its still very unclear. ARe you trying to find 1) offset or the 2) what % of the change needed to convert width to offest? 3) Someting totally diff?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find what x equals to (which is customary for equations):
70 / 100 * 50 (that is we calculate the 150% of 70) / 50 (this is 1% of x) * 100

UPD: Based on more comments, i think you'd be better off using some hard-coded values instead of calculated ones.

`var myPercentage = 0;`

if (initPercentage <= 50) {
    myPercentage = 150;
} else if (initPercentage > 50 and initPercentage <= 100) {
    ...
}

Comment: I dont think he needs to find x, which is what I asked in my comment.

Comment: In fact, for my calculation, "70" is a constant. More my image is larger (>100%) more my offset needs to be smaller. This is also apply in inverted situation (my image is smaller <100%, more my offset needs to be bigger).

Comment: So you need to find the offset, based on other params?

Comment: I don't get it then. 150% of 70 != 50% of 1920... What should be in proportion to what?

Comment: @smk I'm sorry, my english is bad but I think this is what i need. I need to get the "relative offset" based on other parameters.

Comment: @lbolit because 1920 is irrelevant for the calculation. This number needs to be any number in the future.

Comment: Are you trying to center an image?

Comment: @JesseLee no, i have an resized image and i need to know the relative offset. I just know that, 100% of the width of the original image = 70px.

Comment: The 200% to %25 ratio throws the pattern from being a linear ratio equation. Can't be certain to extrapolate into an equation when this one ratio throws the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not a linear equation at the very least:

```
function test(x){return x*-1 + 200}
alert(test(50)) // okay 150
alert(test(100)) // okay 100 
alert(test(150)) // okay 50
alert(test(200)) // wrong 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/Skss2/

Comment: Yes, this is not linear what i need. This is exponential.

Comment: Its a highly skewed dataset. Your best best is quadratic : http://www.seomoz.org/labs_tools/online-regression/?data=50+150%0D%0A100+100%0D%0A150+50%0D%0A200+25

Comment: since it goes linearly between the first three points and then jumps you cannot get a smooth equation no matter exponential / quadratic, whatever

Comment: please check my update to the original question I made a illustration. I hope it's help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic mathematic problem where:

```
a% * x = b% * 70
```

Solving for x, first expand the terms (order of * and / is not significant here):

```
a * x / 100 = b * 70 / 100
```

multiply both sides by 100

```
a * x = b * 70
```

divide both sides by a:

```
x = b * 70 / a
```

So now given a and b you can solve for x. Let `a = 50` and `b = 150`, then:

```
x = 150 * 70 / 50
x = 210
```

Test: 150% of 70 = 105 and 50% of 210 = 105, so it works.

**But** then you have:

```
100% of (x) = 100% of 70
```

which means `x == 70`, which is inconsistent, and then:

```
150% of (x) = 50% of 70
```

which means `x = 23.33333333`, which is again inconsistent.

You could do a least square solution to work out the best value for x, but likely the values are so widely spread it wouldn't be much use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. I resolved my issue but my logic was wrong. I'm sorry.
I used Excel to find my formula.